# Flutter bloc pattern Structure problem(Sending form data from the Ui the Provider)

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc

When I'm sending forms data to the server in bloc pattern I should send form data from Ui to Bloc class from bloc class to repository from the repository to the provider and from provider to the server. I think it is not the right way.